# JBoss EAP 7.0 startup error

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I've installed JBoss on a CentOS 7 virtual machine and Jboss tools on Eclipse Oxygen. I'm only trying to start server via Eclipse, without any project to deploy.

But i've received this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from /opt/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/msc/main/module.xml
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:228)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:204)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:170)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.lambda$findModule$0(LocalModuleFinder.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:144)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:439)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:342)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:289)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1229)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1121)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1448)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1476)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:396)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add resource root 'jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final-redhat-1.jar' at path 'jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final-redhat-1.jar' (position: END_TAG seen ...        <resource-root path="jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final-redhat-1.jar"/>... @34:67) caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResourceRoot(ModuleXmlParser.java:891)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java:735)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:535)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:340)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:226)
    ... 14 more
[1]+  Exit 1                  java "-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.0" -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss-eap-7.0/standalone/log/boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss-eap-7.0/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" "-Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss-eap-7.0" -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true -jar /opt/jboss-eap-7.0/jboss-modules.jar -mp "/opt/jboss-eap-7.0/modules" org.jboss.as.standalone -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/jboss-eap-7.0/standalone
JBTOOLS_SERVER_LAUNCH_TERMINATED_CMD:Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.01504388944983: 1
```

Comment: Does your JBoss start successfully when you launch it outside of Eclipse? `zip file is empty` for the `jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final-redhat-1.jar` means nothing else but corrupted JBoss installation. Barely, but JBoss Tools plugin may be in charge for that, but let's check if JBoss is OK itself first

Comment: Thank you. My installation was corrupted. I reinstalled Jboss and it works now.